# Insert into table ps_order_payment prestashop

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, payment

I have a payment module from which I validate an order with validateOrder:

```
                $this->module->validateOrder(
                ( int ) $this->context->cart->id,
                Configuration::get( 'PS_OS_PAYMENT' ),
                ( float ) $this->context->cart->getOrderTotal( true, Cart::BOTH ),
                $this->module->displayName,
                null,
                null,
                ( int ) $this->context->currency->id,
                false,
                $customer->secure_key
            );
```

When that happens automatically a record is created in the ps_order_payment table (id_order_payment, order_reference, etc) in that table there is also a field called card_holder, but there it does not save anything, I want to know how to save that record and from where it is done?

I have the idea that it is from the orderPayment.php class

Comment: Using float values for money is going to be trouble, so be careful. You're liable to lose a cent here and there due to rounding issues.

Comment: `card_holder` is not a column from `ps_orders` table, it has been created by a module or custom development.

Comment: should someone like you be storing card data in his database in the first place???? hardly doubt it!! There's payment solutions where the card data is not gonna be stored in your database, go and get one of those. you're hardly trustworthy

Answer (score -1):

You can update the card_holder field when you create a new OrderPayment object and then save it to the db.

```
$order_payment = new OrderPayment();
...update other fields
$order_payment->card_holder = 'some string';

$order_payment->add();
```

See the [addOrderPayment method on the OrderCore class](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/order/Order.php#L1842) for the default method.